# Android Studio Preview Issue, Important SDK Tools?

Tags: android, sdk, preview

I'm totally new with android development. I installed android studio today. By default, I'm getting 15 options that can be installed in sdk manager, but my net is limited, so I cannot install all of these :( Can you please suggest the most important of these to install so that preview option should work? I need to target smartphones only: no TV or wearables.

[image: Screenshot of available packages to install]

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are "totally new with android development", **please** do not work with the M Developer Preview. If you want to experiment with some future N Developer Preview, perhaps next year, that is fine. But developer previews are complicated enough for experienced Android developers; you are likely to become rather frustrated if you try using it lacking that experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to download the same options for 2 different API levels: You should get API 21 (or whatever API level is your target API) and whatever API you set as the minimum SDK for your app. You make these designations when you first create your project in Android Studio, or can change them in build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml.

You will probably want the SDK Tools, SDK Build-tools, SDK Platform, Sources for Android SDK, and the Intel x86 images from both API levels your app supports - minimum SDK and target SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Google USB Driver** for sure if you want to use a device for debugging and the **Android Support Library**.

And if you want to use an emulator you have to download one of the **Intel x86 images** (for phone).